# Why am I getting a segmentation fault in C?

Tags: c, runtime-error, cs50

I am getting segmentation error when trying to do the *CS50 Crack* cryptography problem. I am a novice in C language. The code compiles Ok but when I run the debugger it seems to get the following error:

```
Process received SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault
...at guess[0] = *alphabet1;
```

I have looked at other stack overflow questions and suspect it could have something to do with `string` guess being a string literal but this has muddied the waters for me. Can you please explain to me why I am getting segmentation error or direct me to a good webpage to research this. The pertinent code is below.

```
string guess = "     ";
string hashed_word = "     ";
string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";
string letters1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char *alphabet;
char *alphabet1;


//check a-Z
for (int j = 0; j < 52; j++)
{
    alphabet1 = &letters1[j];
    guess[0] = *alphabet1;
    hashed_word = guess;
    if (strcmp(hashed_word, s) == 0)
    {
        print(guess);
    }
}
```

Comment: More generally, please edit your code to make it a [mcve].  That shouldn't take very much, I think, but don't make us guess, because the details may make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

The CS50 header file `cs50.h` defines

```
typedef char *string;
```

So when you define and initialise

```
string guess = "     ";
```

this is the same as

```
char *guess = "     ";
```

and so you assign the value of `guess` to point to a string literal.

So as you surmise in the question, this is the problem with

```
guess[0] = *alphabet1;
```

You must not write to a string literal's data, although you may change the value of the pointer, for example if you want to change a default response in your program.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't show us the concrete header you've included, I suppose it is `cs50.h`.
This header defines: `typedef char * string`.

`char * guess = "     ";` here you're allocating a char Pointer on the stack, which points to a *string literal*. String Literals are normally located in a special segment. (Mostly rodata, but the standard doesn't dictate where).

But the [C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) standard says:

> EXAMPLE 8: The declaration
>
> ```
> char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";
> ```
>
> defines "plain" char array objects s and t whose elements are initialized with character string literals.
>
> This declaration is identical to
>
> ```
> char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' },
>      t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
> ```
>
> The contents of the arrays are modifiable. On the other hand, the declaration
>
> ```
> char *p = "abc";
> ```
>
> defines p with type "pointer to char" and initializes it to point to an > object with type "array of char" with length 4 whose elements are initialized with a character string literal. If an attempt is made to use > p to modify the contents of the array, the behavior is **undefined**.

Comment: string literals are placed usually in the .rodata segment, but definitely not in the .data segment which is placed in RW memory and hosts initialized static storage variables

Comment: The page you point to for [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) says it can be modified. Constant data is often placed in a const/rodata or text segment. (Neither can be modified, but text is for executable code and must be marked executable, whereas const/rodata is for data and does not need to be executable.)

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. I read a long time ago about it here, but your arguments are plausible. I corrected that and used the C99 Standard as source.